# Rank query search via two IDs and then merge

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I basically have this already:

```
SELECT APPID, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table 
    WHERE APPID = alias.APPID 
    AND end > (php time()) 
    AS COUNT
  )
FROM table AS alias
GROUP BY APPID
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Which I am using to rank what APPID has the most entrys, but now I have a problem.

I have two tables games_steam, games_other from two different APIs. To create a link between them i have added a "steamappid" column to games_other. because of the two tables a game can have two APPIDS inside that rank search, Is there anyway of searching for where the steam_games.APPID shows up in games_other.steamappid and in the rank, merge (merge to games_other.APPID is the main ID) where those are related?

If this makes sense?

Example:

games_other

```
.# | APPID | NAME | steamappid |  
----------------------------------------;  
1 | 440 | game 1 | NULL |  
2 | 654 | game 2 | S423  |  
3 | 435 | game 3 | S35   |
```

games_steam

```
.# | APPID | NAME |    
-----------------------;    
1 | S35 | game 3 |  
2 | S86 | game 4 |  
3 | S423 | game 2 |
```

entries

```
ID | APPID  
0  | S35  
1  | 435  
2  | S35   
2  | 435  
3  | 440  
4  | 654  
5  | 654  
5  | S423  
0  | S86
```

So when they are ranked and sorted from entries it would show:

```
APPID | COUNT  

435 | 4  
654 | 3  
S86 | 1  
440 | 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added (even though no idea how to do tables in markdown)

Comment: Sorry yeah, just edited it.

Comment: Your table structures are a mess, hard to follow, I would start by creating a table called games_link where I would hold what is the link between those 2 tables you early mentioned. Can you explain your entries table and why there are repeated IDs and on the desired result why 435 have a count of 4?

Comment: @Prix Entries was just a simplified thing, the real one looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/6OyI3i1.png . It has a count of 4 because in games_other, It contains the steam appid for the related steam game "S35", so when ranked they should be shown as one thing, not two seperate ID's.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain if I understood what you want but is it possible that you come along without a subselect and use a join instead like this?

```
SELECT gs.APPID, COUNT(gs.APPID) AS total_count
FROM games_steam gs
LEFT JOIN games_other go
ON gs.APP_ID = go.steamappid
GROUP BY gs.APPID
```